# How catch ACTION.MOVE_UP without blocking Recycler View event?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to get the position of the element in the MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and after move the element get his last position (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP).
But, when i wrote return false in the onInterceptTouchEvent,  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is not invoked. 
And when i wrote true in the onInterceptTouchEvent, it is invoked ACTION_UP, but blocked the recycler view events.

```
@Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
            View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Log.d("Action", "ACTION_UP");
                 Log.d("view", ((TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.quest_row_title)).getText().toString());

            }
            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Log.d("Action", "ACTION_DOWN");
                Log.d("view", ((TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.quest_row_title)).getText().toString());
                Integer count = view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView);

            }


            if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {

                mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            }

            return false;
        }


public class PageRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PageRecyclerView.PageViewHolder> implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Page> pages;
    public static HashMap<Integer, Editable> editable;

    public PageRecyclerView (ArrayList<Page> pages)
    {
        this.pages = pages;

    }

    @Override
    public PageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View addView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.page_row, parent, false);
        return new PageViewHolder(addView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PageViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.title.setText(pages.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.idPage.setText(String.valueOf(pages.get(position).getIdPage()));
        holder.countSteps.setText(String.valueOf(pages.get(position).getCountSteps()));
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
        pages.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemMoved(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int fromPos, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target, int toPos, int x, int y) {


        Log.d("Positions moved", "Fromposition"+fromPos+"toPosition"+toPos);
        Log.d("Positions movedkj", "With id"+((PageViewHolder)viewHolder).idPage.getText().toString()+"toPosition WIth id"+((PageViewHolder)target).idPage.getText().toString());
        Integer idFrom = Integer.valueOf(((PageViewHolder)viewHolder).idPage.getText().toString());
        Integer idTo= Integer.valueOf(((PageViewHolder)target).idPage.getText().toString());
        if( (PageViewActivity.editableHashMap.get(idFrom))==null){
            PageViewActivity.editableHashMap.put(idTo, new Editable(new Page(idFrom,fromPos), new Page(idTo,toPos)));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        Log.d("Positions", "Fromposition"+fromPosition+"toPosition"+toPosition+"Listsize"+pages.size());
        if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                Collections.swap(pages, i, i + 1);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                Collections.swap(pages, i, i - 1);
            }
        }
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        return true;
    }


    public static class PageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView idPage;
        TextView countSteps;
        public PageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.page_row_title);
            idPage = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.page_row_id_page);
            countSteps = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.page_row_count_steps);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? it smells like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I have a drag&drop recyclerview, and i want to get of the element position before moving, position after moving (after MotionEvent.ACTION_UP).

Comment: [ItemTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html)?

Comment: i use, but i need to get ACTION_UP to start my custom method

Comment: then override `ItemTouchHelper.Callback#onSelectedChanged` method

Comment: Thank you for answer ^_^

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
return false;
```

try to return this and see

```
return view.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
```

this will not intercept default touch events

Comment: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i am still can't catch the ACTION_UP java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the answer  @pskink, we need to override two methods onSelectedChanged (like ACTION_DOWN) and ClearView (like ACTION_UP).

```
@Override
public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
    // We only want the active item to change
    if (actionState != ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) {
            // Let the view holder know that this item is being moved or dragged
            ItemTouchHelperViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) viewHolder;
            itemViewHolder.onItemSelected();
            Log.d("onSelectedChanged",((PageRecyclerView.PageViewHolder)itemViewHolder).idPage.getText().toString());
            Log.d("onSelectedChanged", String.valueOf(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
        }
    }

    super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);
}

@Override
public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);

    viewHolder.itemView.setAlpha(ALPHA_FULL);

    if (viewHolder instanceof ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) {
        // Tell the view holder it's time to restore the idle state

        ItemTouchHelperViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) viewHolder;
        Log.d("onClearView",((PageRecyclerView.PageViewHolder)itemViewHolder).idPage.getText().toString());
        itemViewHolder.onItemClear();
        Log.d("onClearView","test");
        Log.d("onClearView", String.valueOf(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
    }
```